# Determine maximum of $|f(z)| \: \: \mbox{for}\: z \in$ unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = z^2 + z -1$. How to calculate the maximum of $|f(z)|$ for $z \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$? I've tried $z = \exp(it) \:\: t \in \mathbb{R}$, but I wasn't able to get a solution this way. 
Is there like a general way of solving these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to establish that the maximum can occur only on the boundary. For that use the max-modulus principle: the function being non-constant has to have the maximum on the boundary only ($|z|=1$). Now use the idea given by @dxiv to maximize
$$|f(z)|=|z||(1+2i\operatorname{Im}(z))|=\sqrt{1+4\sin^2 \theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  on the unit circle $|z|=1$ the function is equivalent to $f(z)=z\big(1 + 2i \operatorname{Im}(z)\big)$.

Comment: Since you had this idea first, I'm not sure why your answer was not given the √.

Comment: @zhw. The accepted answer graciously acknowledged that, but the √ is OP's call in the end, and I have no qualms about it.